# Installing Ubuntu 23.04 desktop on top of server takes forever

Tags: server, raid, .desktop

Because server installer can handle various disk situations (for example create md disk array and install on it) I always install server first and follow it with "apt install ubuntu-desktop"). This always worked fine, however I'm observing strange behavior with just released 23.04. Server installs fine but trying to install desktop on top of it takes literally forever. It just hangs every few steps passed about 50% of packages. And while this is going on I can't ssh to the box, it hangs as well. I don't actually know if it's ever going to finish. Any idea what is going on? And maybe there is a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?